# How to pass a JS object to a server function using google.script.run in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, templates, google-apps-script

I want to pass an object to a server function using Google Apps Script. But I'm having a problem doing it this way.

```
<?= config.bob ?>
<button type="button" onclick="google.script.run.sayHiObject(<?= config ?>)">
  Run Bob
</button>
```

When I click the button labeled <kbd>Run Bob</kbd>, I expect to see an alert prompt that says:

> Hi, Bob!

But instead, it says:

> Hi, undefined!

[This page says:](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

> Legal parameters are JavaScript primitives like a Number, Boolean, String, or null, **as well as JavaScript objects** and arrays that are composed of primitives, objects, and arrays. [Emphasis mine]

So, I assume it's possible to pass an object. However, my demo shown below only proves it's possible to pass a string that way. The object seems to have a problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Fig. 1. Demo. <kbd>Run Alice</kbd> and <kbd>Run Charlie</kbd> successfully pass strings as arguments. But <kbd>Run Bob</kbd> fails to pass an object as the argument.

[image]

Code.gs

```
var TITLE = 'Say hi to:';
var HTML_FILENAME = 'index';
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

function handleEdit(e) {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(HTML_FILENAME);
  template.alice = 'Alice';
  template.config = { bob: 'Bob', charlie: 'Charlie' };
  var htmlOutput = template.evaluate();
  ui.showModalDialog(htmlOutput, TITLE);
}

function sayHi(name) {
  var msg = 'Hi, ' + name + '!';
  ui.alert(msg);
}

function sayHiString(name) {
  sayHi(name);
}

function sayHiObject(config) {
  sayHi(config.name);
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <body>
      <?= alice ?>
      <button type="button" onclick="google.script.run.sayHiString(<?= alice ?>)">
        Run Alice
      </button>

      <?= config.bob ?>
      <button type="button" onclick="google.script.run.sayHiObject(<?= config ?>)">
        Run Bob
      </button>

      <?= config.charlie ?>
      <button type="button" onclick="google.script.run.sayHiString(<?= config.charlie ?>)">
        Run Charlie
      </button>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

When `template.config = { bob: 'Bob', charlie: 'Charlie' , name: "sample"};` is used as `<?= config ?>`, `<?= config ?>` becomes `[object Object]`. By this, such issue occurs. On the other hand, `<?= config.charlie ?>` becomes `'Charlie'` which is a string. By this, the script works. So please use the string type as the value.

In order to work your script, how about the following modification?

### Modified script:

#### From:

```
<button type="button" onclick="google.script.run.sayHiObject(<?= config ?>)">
```

#### To:

```
<button type="button" onclick="google.script.run.sayHiObject(JSON.parse(<?= JSON.stringify(config) ?>))">
```

And also, in your script, `{ bob: 'Bob', charlie: 'Charlie' }` has no `name` propery. So for example, also please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
template.config = { bob: 'Bob', charlie: 'Charlie' };
```

#### To:

```
template.config = { bob: 'Bob', charlie: 'Charlie', name: 'sample' };
```

### Reference:

- [HTML Service: Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

Hi  try to change   `config` to  `config.bob`

in `<button type="button" onclick="google.script.run.sayHiObject(<?= config ?>)">`

like this

in `<button type="button" onclick="google.script.run.sayHiObject(<?= config.bob ?>)">`