# Generate Recurrent Payment Link Stripe With Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, stripe-payments

I am a beginner in the API world and I am trying to develop new skills.
I found this code on the Internet. I understand it in general but I would like to add the option to add a description to my Payment link generation but I am not used to this format. I search into the Stripe documentation but Google Script needs a conversion to work properly, so it doesn't look the same way in the Stripe doc.

To finish, I would like to create a recurrent Payment Link and not a one-time payment link.

I don't know if I am clear enough.

```
/**
 *
 *  Author   :  Amit Agarwal
 *  Email    :  amit@labnol.org
 *  Website  :  https://digitalinspiration.com/
 *  License. :  MIT Attribution required
 *
 * */

const StripeAPI = {
  getCache(key) {
    return CacheService.getScriptCache().get(key);
  },

  setCache(key, value) {
    CacheService.getScriptCache().put(key, value, 21600);
  },

  convertPayload(params = {}) {
    return Object.entries(params)
      .map(([key, value]) => [encodeURIComponent(key), encodeURIComponent(value)].join('='))
      .join('&');
  },

  getData(endpoint, params) {
    const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(`${endpoint}?${this.convertPayload(params)}`, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${STRIPE_API_KEY}`,
      },
      muteHttpExceptions: true,
    });
    return JSON.parse(response);
  },

  postData(endpoint, params) {
    const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(endpoint, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${STRIPE_API_KEY}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
      muteHttpExceptions: true,
      payload: this.convertPayload(params),
    });

    return JSON.parse(response);
  },

  getProductId(name) {
    const productId = this.getCache(name);
    if (productId) return productId;
    const api = 'https://api.stripe.com/v1/products';
    const { data = [] } = this.getData(api, { limit: 100 });
    const { id: newProductId } =
      data.find(({ name: productName }) => productName === name) || this.postData(api, { name });
    this.setCache(name, newProductId);
    return newProductId;
  },

  getPriceId(name, price = '1234', currency = 'USD') {
    const product_id = this.getProductId(name);
    const key = product_id + price + currency;
    const priceId = this.getCache(key);
    if (priceId) return priceId;
    const api = 'https://api.stripe.com/v1/prices';
    const { data = [] } = this.getData(api, { limit: 100, currency, product: product_id });
    const { id: newPriceId } =
      data.find(({ unit_amount }) => String(unit_amount) === String(price)) ||
      this.postData(api, { currency, product: product_id, unit_amount: price });
    this.setCache(key, newPriceId);
    return newPriceId;
  },

  createLink(name, amount, currency) {
    const key = `link${amount}${currency}${name}`;
    const paymentLink = this.getCache(key);
    if (paymentLink) return paymentLink;
    const priceId = this.getPriceId(name, Math.ceil(amount * 100), currency);
    const { url } = this.postData('https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_links', {
      'line_items[0][price]': priceId,
      'line_items[0][quantity]': 1,
    });
    this.setCache(key, url);
    return url;
  },

  createSession(name, amount, currency) {
    const STRIPE_SUCCESS_URL = 'youtube.com';
    const STRIPE_CANCEL_URL = 'bing.fr';
    const key = `session${amount}${currency}${name}`;
    const sessionLink = this.getCache(key);
    if (sessionLink) return sessionLink;
    const { url } = this.postData('https://api.stripe.com/v1/checkout/sessions', {
      cancel_url: STRIPE_CANCEL_URL,
      success_url: STRIPE_SUCCESS_URL,
      mode: 'payment',
      billing_address_collection: 'required',
      'payment_method_types[]': 'card',
      'line_items[0][price_data][currency]': currency,
      'line_items[0][price_data][product_data][name]': name,
      'line_items[0][price_data][unit_amount]': Math.ceil(amount * 100),
      'line_items[0][quantity]': 1,
    });
    this.setCache(key, url);
    return url;
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a description to your Payment Links you need to pass a [description](https://stripe.com/docs/api/products/create#create_product-description) parameter when you create the Product in your `getProductId()` method and pass that with your postData.

In terms of creating a Subscription from your Payment Link, you need to add the [recurring.interval](https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/create#create_price-recurring-interval) parameter to your Price creation in your `getPriceId()` method and pass that with your postData.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I succeded to add a description in my product modifying this line :             `data.find(({ name: productName }) => productName === name) || this.postData(api, { name, description: descriptionPrice });`

Comment: But I am struggling with the recurring.interval,  I tried that: `const { data = [] } = this.getData(api, { limit: 100, currency, product: product_id, recurring: {interval: 'month'} });` but it doesn't work could you help me please ?

Comment: Here you added `recurring` to the `getData` request which is retrieving your Prices to see if one already exists so you don't create duplicates. Instead you want to add the `recurring` parameter to your `postData` function like you did with your Products above.

Comment: Hello, excuse me I copy paste the wrong line. I added the recurring paramater into the post data function.  `this.postData(api, { currency, product: product_id, unit_amount: price,recurring: {"interval":"month"}, nickname: "17"});` but I received an error in Stripe telling me that's an invalid object. The POST DATA display that   {
  "recurring": "[object Object]",
  "unit_amount": "19500",
  "product": "prod_M5RDsg32bfzwAx",
  "currency": "EUR",
  "nickname": "16"
} I tried to stringigy the date but no success.

Comment: When you said you tried to stringify did you use JSON.stringify() for your object? Sounds like you will need to do something similar to what is referenced here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60086591/how-to-pass-a-js-object-to-a-server-function-using-google-script-run-in-google-a.

Comment: `getPriceId(name, price = '1234', currency = 'EUR') {

    const recurring_data = {interval: "month", usage_type: "licensed"}

    const recurring_data_Json = JSON.stringify(recurring_data)
    const recurring_data_JS = JSON.parse(recurring_data_Json)
    const recurring_data_object = recurring_data_JS.interval
    
    [....]
      this.postData(api, { currency, product: product_id, unit_amount: price, recurring: recurring_data_object});
    this.setCache(key, newPriceId);
    return newPriceId;
  },` but I can only get the data from a specific field.

Comment: I can't send all {interval: "month", usage_type: "licensed"} into the recurring field.