# Pass JavaScript Object data from client side HTML to server side using google app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

When the button is clicked, I want to capture the email ID and account name and pass this information to the server side.

The code works on the client side, but the server function does not fire, but it fails. I can see it under the execution log ad Failed.

I also tried using JSON stringify in the code. gs function, but doesn't work either.

**HTML**

```
<script>

  

$('#btn').click(function () {

  console.log('Button is clicked');

          
            var accountId = $('select#accountData').val();
            console.log(accountId);
            var emailId = $('input#emailaddressId').val();
            console.log(emailId);

            var gaAccountData = {};

            gaAccountData.account = accountId
            gaAccountData.email = emailId
            console.log(gaAccountData);

            gaAccountData=JSON.stringify(gaAccountData)
            gaAccountData=JSON.parse(gaAccountData)
            google.script.run.onboardUsertoAccount(gaAccountData);
        });

</script>
```

**Code.gs**

```
function onboardUsertoAccount(gaAccountData) {


    const Userdata = {
        "emailAddress": gaAccountData.email,
        "directRoles": [
            "predefinedRoles/viewer"
        ]
    }
    AnalyticsAdmin.Accounts.UserLinks.create(Userdata, gaAccountData.account, {
        "notifyNewUser": false
    });
}
```

Comment: What is your error from server side? Add ```Logger.log(gaAccountData)``` inside your function ```onboardUsertoAccount```

Comment: I tried adding ```Logger.log(gaAccountData)``` right after ```onboardUsertoAccount``` function. It doesn't log any error but under the execution log, it says Failed

Comment: An answer for a similar thing from a few years ago. Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60086591/how-to-pass-a-js-object-to-a-server-function-using-google-script-run-in-google-a

Comment: Yes, I followed the instructions from this thread. But somehow it doesn't work. Can you take a look?

Comment: Comment the lines regarding AnalyticsAdmin, and Execute your server function from the project file. Is it running?

Comment: Plus, it’s strange you don’t have any log detail for your error. Maybe you are trying with /exec url? You should do /dev

Comment: When I run the onboardUsertoAccount function from the code.gs editor, it gives me an error - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'email').

Previously, I was clicking on the sidebar HTML button and adding the user via the front-end. The execution logs say onboard... function fails. I am not sure what you mean do/dev or /exec url

Comment: I also commented out Analytics Admin. It gives me an error - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'email'). This is probably because email is added by the user from front-end.

Comment: Ok, and when you execute from /dev url you dont have any error? (Click Deploy > Test deployment to get the proper link) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62045820/dev-vs-exec-documentation-and-mishandling

Comment: I haven't deployed the application yet. I can share the sheet with you. If you want to take a look?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250995/discussion-between-waxim-corp-and-arif-ahmed).

Comment: If it's working with hardcode, the problem come from variables. Try to add in javascript : ```gaAccountData=JSON.stringify(gaAccountData)``` like you did (but without the JSON.parse), and add in the .gs : ```var new_gaAccountData=JSON.parse(gaAccountData)```